# Can I use multiple layouts for one view?

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

The main layout that I want to use for all views is connected inside _ViewStart. But I would like to use second layout for some views. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [their docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-3.1#specifying-a-layout)? Your title mentions multiple layouts for one view, but your question states a second layout for some views. You cannot do the first, but most certainly can do the second.

Comment: @BenSampica yeah. If I use @{Layout = "_SecondLayout";} inside view, the first layout replaced by the second layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A page can have only one layout. From your description, I think you can just combine the two layouts as a new layout, then use it for some views.

In addition, I think [Partial View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1#:%7E:text=A%20partial%20view%20is%20a,markup%20files%20are%20called%20pages.) can also meet your needs, you can have a reference.